# PrepareForSegue Swift (changing UIImage and UILabel)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage, segue

So I'm writing the `prepareForSegue` for my app but having issue setting up the code for changing the `UIImage` and `UILabel` for the destination `ViewController`.

What would be the code to change the images and `UILabel` when segue to the next `ViewController`?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toTest") {            
        let destViewController : data3ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as data3ViewController    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I you have in your `data3ViewController` an `UILabel` and an `UIImage` , let says named 
`myLabel` and `myImage` respectively , then you should do the following :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "toTest") {            
      var destViewController : data3ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as data3ViewController   
      let _ =  destViewController.view
      destViewController.myLabel.text = "Something"
      destViewController.myImage = UIImage(named: "photo")
   }
}
```

The call above to `destViewController.view` ensure that the `@IBOutlet`'s are initialized before set it values.

I hope this help you

Comment: override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toTest") {
            
            let destViewController : data3ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as data3ViewController
            
            destViewController.titleLabel.text = "Change Title"
            
            destViewController.connectorImage.image = UIImage(named: "background")

        }

Comment: You must check if your `destViewControlle`r isn't `nil`

Comment: seem like my issue is at the destViewController.myLabel.text = "Something"

Comment: @Coder It was just an sample code, you must recode regarding your needs

Comment: Don't know if @Coder you are still following this thread. In my opinion, this answer must be wrong because `destViewController.myLabel` has not been created yet in `prepareForSegue` func. You need to add a variable in your destViewController as a bridge and assign the label text to be that variable once the destViewController is loaded

Comment: @MoonKnight Yes you're right the `@IBOutlets` are not create yet in the `prepareForSegue`, but you can do what you said in your comment or just call the `view` to force the view controller to call the `loadView` and init the @IBOutlets``.